# Firefighting on shabbat

Tags: shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, employment, fire-burning

Is one allowed to be a firefighter if he might be required to work on Shabbat? or is he allowed to, in order to save lives?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7129/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think that's the same thing -- finding yourself in that situation might be different from choosing an occupation that you know will place you in that situation.  (That said, I know enough Jewish doctors who do or did do rotations in hospitals to suspect that this is permitted, though I don't know under what circumstances.)

Comment: I you are a allowed to break shabbat to save lives, but is someone allowed to pursue a job (firefighting) that he knows will cause him to be mechallel shabbat?

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%93 Who else do you want to do the work? (If you have more info please [edit] it into the question.)

Comment: Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I'm glad to see you've registered your account and I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Do you live in a place with a majority of Jews?

Comment: No..............

Comment: @Ariel It's not about where he lives, but what the question he is asking is. Any lemaaseh question should be posed to his personal Rabbi.

Comment: The issue isn't just about placing oneself in an occupation where you must break Shabbos to save a life, you are also expected to save property.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu We generally assume nowadays that any significant fire is a threat to life because it can easily spread to other buildings. But yes, answers that touch on that would be good.

Comment: @DoubleAA, fine but that is part of the answer, not a negation of the question

Comment: related: http://www.algemeiner.com/2012/10/29/from-long-island-to-israel-orthodox-woman-firefighter/ 
also: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/article.php?p=4012

Comment: Perhaps שלומ בית could influence the necessity to perform the job, and thus the job-necessary function of saving property.

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome! Since your comments seem to reveal more details on the situation, I would recommend editing the question as to include these.

Comment: @NewAlexandria It would be hard to use Shalom Bayit to justify violating clear Biblical prohibitions.

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm contemplating a scenario where one sees no other option for family livelihood.  I think it's off-topic from this question+thread.  Then maybe there is Pikuach Nefesh for one's children.  Situational at most, and one would endeavor to move on from such a job.

Answer (score 4):

When I was an EMT I lived in a place where there were many Jews in the rescue squad.  The local rabbis told us to arrange a rotation which ensured that there was always someone to answer calls but that we didnt have more people than we need.

I would say that Jewish firefighters should try not to be on-call on shabbat but if they need to respond to life threatening emergencies they must.

Comment: This sounds like a huge risk to me. Weren't you ever short a person?

Comment: But what about the duty to extinguish a fire to save property, either after the people have been brought to safety or to save an empty building? What if there no significant danger of it spreading?

Comment: if we were ever short we had mutual aid from other neighboring towns.  there were also backups on call.

Comment: tAs far as I know there is no permission to extinguish fire to save only property.  If ther eis a danger of spreading or to life and limb (which there almost always is) then of course the fire must be extinguished.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, since Fire-Fighting is all about rescuing lives (~ Pikuach Nefesh, פיקוח נפש) then it has priority over all other Mitzvas.

Source from Wikipedia: [Here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%97_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%97%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA).

Comment: Felix, welcome to M.Y.  Unfortunately, as mentioned in several comments already, firefighting involves saving property, not just lives.  How do you justify that under פיקוח נפש?

Comment: isnt a large fire considered a threat to life

Comment: @SethJ, as long as it's also lives - it's פיקוח נפש.

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1390.