# Is Pinchas of Balak/Pinchas same Pinchas as Shoftim?

Tags: historical-figures, pinchas, shoftim--book-of, zealotry

Is [the Pinchas from the generation that left Egypt](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%96) the same as [the Pinchas mentioned in Shoftim 20](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B_%D7%9B%D7%97)?

Pinchas's zealotry earns him an eternal priesthood because of going above the letter of the law and risking his own life (al pi Rashi) to exact judgement.

The Pinchas of Shoftim calls on Israel to battle Binyomin to the point of nearly exterminating the tribe. In this case the zealotry isn't a positive choice and because of this error causes thousands of Jews to perish.

I am interested in anyones findings in the Gemara, Commentary on Tanach, etc. that connect these two Pinchas individuals as the same and also discuss the topic of zealotry.

Comment: It would be a pretty big coincidence IMO to have two leaders with the same name, the same father's name, and the same grandfather's name.

Comment: What makes you say the zealousness in Shoftim was an error? Wasn't he just saying what God told him to?

Comment: @DoubleAA RAMBAN seems to think so when saying that they were blinded by pride to the point of a full scale war.

Comment: The _people_ were blinded by pride to the point of full scale war. All Pinechas did was ask God. God is the One Who said Go. I don't see where Pinechas did anything zealous at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good [article](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/salt-bemidbar/41-6pinchas.htm), and it brings sources that Pinchas of these parashiyos is the same as the Pinchas of Shoftim.

Comment: You answer would be much improved if you'd summarize also instead of only linking.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8595/if-eliyahu-is-pinchas-and-pinchas-is-a-cohen-how-was-he-in-the-room-when-he-did/8599#8599 brings the Ibn Ezra who confirms this.