# Does one wash his hands upon waking up from cryostasis?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

[Assuming that cryonics is permissible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17835/):

NASA is [reportedly looking into cryostasis technology](https://www.universetoday.com/115265/nasa-investigating-deep-space-hibernation-technology/) in preparation for a Mars mission. As I understand the theoretical technology, any astronauts who would undergo this procedure would wake up fully refreshed – that is, this is inducing *sleep*, rather than a coma.

Let's say that a Jew were on that flight. After waking up, must he wash his hands, as he would after waking up from an ordinary sleep?

Certainly according to the Rashba (cited by Mishnah Berurah 4:1), that one washes his hands in the morning because he's considered a new being, he would still wash his hands upon waking up from cryostasis.

However, according to the Rosh (also cited by Mishnah Berurah 4:1), that it's because one may have touched a body part that's ordinarily covered, this isn't a concern during cryostasis, and perhaps one would not need to wash his hands upon waking up. Or, maybe we don't distinguish between the different types of cases.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30683/

Comment: We already are choshesh for both shittos acc to MB,the question of wearing gloves would also give rise to this bracha questiom.

Comment: I seem to recall that this machlokes is the reason that we wash our hands without a b’racha after an all-nighter.