# On "he who saved one life saves the world"

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, gifts, parts-of-the-body, maseches-sanhedrin

According to Talmud ([Mishnah Sanhedrin 4:5; Babylonian Talmud Tractate Sanhedrin 37a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=37&format=text)),

> Whoever destroys a soul, it is considered as if he destroyed an entire
>   world. And whoever saves a life, it is considered as if he saved an
>   entire world.

I wonder, does it apply to someone who donated blood to be used as part of a transfusion?

For the purposes of this question, lets assume:

- The blood was received by a person who would die without blood transfusion
- Giver's blood was received by chance. There is nothing specific about giver's blood other then that it was available when needed and was of right type
- Giver does not know whether blood was used to save a life or as part of a routine surgery

Comment: Hello JAM and welcome to J.SE! Thanks for bringing your very interesting question here. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Vram Do you know that they throw out extra blood every so often? I doubt they do. If they don't then your blood is guaranteed to save someone's life (or 3 people). This is especially true of O- blood which is rare and useful.

Comment: Agreed with @DoubleAA comment 5

Comment: @Vram Certainly for the rarer blood types. Note that blood has a shelf life of some time so the supply and demand even themselves out over time.

Comment: @DoubleAA, they do _sometimes_ throw out blood, I know. After 9/11, for instance, there were throngs of donors, and blood was wasted. In general, though, I *suspect* they wind up using all usable blood.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3126/organ-donations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand the question.
The statement that a person who saves one life, saves the world is an aggadic statement, not a halachic one.  Halacha does not allow you to sacrifice one life for the sake of many.

If you save a life, that is a great and wonderful thing.  If you think you are saving a life, but don't actually do so, it doesn't take away the good actions that you are doing.  It does not matter if you actually save a life, or just get yourself into a position to help save a life, all are great and wonderful things to do.

Moral dictums that may never apply, or may not apply based on the particularities of a case, are still valid as general moral statements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course donating blood to a total stranger counts as saving a life. If you donate $10 to feed the hungry or help the tornado victims in Moore, OK, it doesn't matter if other people give more. You still did it. As a Catholic Christian nurse I have performed the Heimlich maneuver on choking geriatric patients several times. This is not heroic in a health care center but I was there and did it so I count that also.

Comment: welcome to Mi Yodeya sharon, thanks for this answer. adding sources to support your claim would improve this answer as well.