Research shows that the human brain may stay active for hours after death. Implications for halacha?
[QUESTION SIGNIFICANTLY REVISED]
There has been research that showed that

"the time death is declared when the heart stops beating. As
the heart stops beating, it stops pumping blood to the brain and
slowly the brain begins to shut down …. this process of the brain
shutting down slowly may take hours and the person may be dead during
this time but aware of their surroundings".

I understand that halacha says that life is determined by autonomous breathing and heartbeat.
Has there been any discussion of the implications of this new research in the halachic literature?
Is it reasonable to assert that a person is dead while still aware of their surroundings?

Can you elaborate on how animal lives and organs matter Halachicly?

If the same could be achieved with humans, then one could question whether the stopping of autonomous breathing and heartbeat is a sufficient definition of death.

The original question only spoke about animals. I have now added what is known about humans.

why would them feeling make a difference? קשה רימה למת כמחט בבשר החי. In halacha we only care about what we can see (bugs in food, gemara says maggots spontaneously grow, acc. to some electricity on shabbat).

Did you see the word "brain" in Halachah? Death is about the Neshoma leaving the body. Since Neshomo is [linked with] breath ( וַיִּפַּח בְּאַפָּיו נִשְׁמַת חַיִּים וַיְהִי הָאָדָם לְנֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה), death is when breathing stops.

Your last question is not related to this space.

It's pretty well known that there is a dispute if heartbeat or brain death is the relevant line https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/376/759

There are at least two books on the subject.

David Shabtai "Defining the Moment", Kodesh Press 2013
Naftali Moses "Really Dead", 2011


I believe that there is much discussion about how the soul hovers around the body at least until burial, and the like. I would say if science is finally aware as well, this is progress in science catching up to Torah.
